# Resource creation failed using .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a DynamoDB table in a bare-bones node project using a config file in `.ebextensions`. The app launches successfully but the table never gets created. My project structure looks like this:

```
app/
  .elasticbeanstalk/
    config.yml
  .ebextensions/
    setup.config
  app.js
```

setup.config contains the following:

```
Resources:
  StartupSignupsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        HashKeyElement:
          AttributeName: "email"
          AttributeType: "S"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

I then run the following commands to make a new elasticbeanstalk application:

```
git init
eb init
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit."
eb create
```

The application launches, but with errors:

```
ERROR: Creating security group named: sg-8c926717 failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
ERROR: Stack named 'awseb-f-nrju2hums2-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  
Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [StartupSignupsTable, AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup].
INFO: Launched environment: test-dev. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is unknown.
```

Does anyone have any clue about what's preventing the table from being made? I'm using a modified EB IAM role with full DynamoDB privileges. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong. Turns out the user I had associated with the `eb` CLI did not have appropriate privileges to create DynamoDB tables. Adding the DynamoDB:CreateTable policy fixed the problem.

Comment: You should maybe add more detail (code/properties that were updated) and mark this as the answer.